# Different serializers for serializing/deserializing using Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got a model with a recursive relationship to itself:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    original = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)
```

And a serializer that renders the original Tweet inline:

```
class TweetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = ('id', 'text', 'original', 'original_id')

    original_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='original_id', required=False)

    def to_native(self, obj):
        ret = super(TweetSerializer, self).to_native(obj)
        del ret['original_id']
        return ret

TweetSerializer.base_fields['original'] = TweetSerializer(source='original', read_only=True)
```

As you can see I've also got an original_id field that is removed in `to_native`. The purpose of `original_id` is to allow me to set the original_id of a new tweet, rather than having to supply a full blown Tweed object to the `original` field. You could say that I'm using it as a write only field. 
This seems a bit clunky though. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

OK, two points:

1. Have you tried using [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#primarykeyrelatedfield) for your `original_id`? It would seem to target your use-case specifically. Combined with the [depth option](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers.html#specifying-nested-serialization) it may give you everything you need.
2. You can switch serializers (e.g. based on request method) by overriding [`get_serializer_class()`](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html#genericapiview) on your view. Not sure if you'll get the exact behaviour you want here though.

Comment: Since I need to output the original tweet inline, and not simply its id, I don't think the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is good enough. If I understand things correctly, rendering related fields inline is done by using another serializer as a field: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations.html#nestedRelationships
`get_serializer_class()` could work if there was a way of distinguishing what the intent is, i.e. serialization or deserialization. I want to use one serializer for input, and another for output, and it doesn't look like `get_serializer_class()` is aware of that context.

Comment: Yes — it's not easily supported (as yet). If it were me I'd look at a custom `Field` (probably extending `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and override `to_native` to get the behaviour. There's [an open pull request](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1071) that could serve you also.